# Returning Null values with COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

With this query, I get a result that is two short of the table because they are not included in count, and I would like get the NULL values in the result. To do this, I am pretty sure I need to use a subquery of some kind, but I am not sure how, since the attribute in question is an aggregate.

```
SELECT Equipment.SerialNo , Name, COUNT(Assignment.SerialNo) 
FROM Equipment
INNER JOIN Assignment
     ON Assignment.SerialNo = Equipment.SerialNo

GROUP BY Equipment.SerialNo, Name
```

Comment: Then what is limiting my result? In this case the items in question do not participate in Assignment.SerialNo, so count would miss them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your `inner join` to a `left outer join` and count something other than `Assignment.SerialNo` if you want all rows counted -- use `count(*)` or another property that will not be null, as `count(column)` does not include nulls for that column. If you don't want null `Assignment.SerialNo` values included in the count, then continue aggregating on that column.

An inner join by definition will skip values where `Assignment.SerialNo` is `NULL`-- an outer join will include them.

Comment: Now I've said that I've changed my mind. Presumably he wants the count to be 0 for the rows that are missing, in which case `Count(Assignment.SerialNo)` is correct.

Comment: Does he? I'm confused by the phrasing. I'll edit for either case.